# punctuation question, usage of semicolon

Tags: semicolons

If I list non-complete sentences, should I use semicolons? I'm solving an English question and I'm totally stuck. Below is the problem. Which one is right?

- Colon introducing the list, with no further punctuation:

  > Konia needed a project structure incorporating three features: (1) merging of the required areas of expertise to cover all relevant dimensions (2) the facilitation of interaction between the areas for rapid accumulation of specialized, process-specific know-how and (3) fast response time to ensure completion of objectives within six months.
- Colon introducing the list, with semi-colons separating each item:

  > Konia needed a project structure incorporating three features: (1) merging of the required areas of expertise to cover all relevant dimensions; (2) the facilitation of interaction between the areas for rapid accumulation of specialized, process-specific know-how; and (3) fast response time to ensure completion of objectives within six months.
- Colon introducing a comma-separated list, with a semi-colon before the  last item:

  > Konia needed a project structure incorporating three features: (1) merging of the required areas of expertise to cover all relevant dimensions, (2) the facilitation of interaction between the areas for rapid accumulation of specialized, process-specific know-how; and (3) fast response time to ensure completion of objectives within six months.
- Semi-colon introducing the list and separating each item:

  > Konia needed a project structure incorporating three features; (1) merging of the required areas of expertise to cover all relevant dimensions; (2) the facilitation of interaction between the areas for rapid accumulation of specialized, process-specific know-how; and (3) fast response time to ensure completion of objectives within six months.

Comment: #1 uses '(number)' as separator, which works. #2 seems cleanest. #3 uses both a comma and a semicolon as list separators -- unclear why. #4 uses the semicolon to introduce the list -- unclear why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any restrict rules about using semicolons in informal contexts. However, semicolons are not used before declaration of a list in academic literature. So, choice 4 is not correct.

It is very common to separate list items using semicolons. Therefore, second list is the best choice.

Note that before the last item, an *and* should be inserted (as it already is in all your cases).

Comment: Friendly advice: If you've flagged for closure as a duplicate, you don't need to provide an answer. Either the question is a duplicate (and the answer is elsewhere), or it's not.